# How do I catch node.js/express server errors like EADDRINUSE?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, coffeescript

This is my code.

```
if !module.parent
    try
        hons_server.listen config.port
        console.log 'Listening to port ' + config.port
    catch err
        console.error "Couldn't start server: #{String(err)}".red
```

`hons_server` is an [express.js server](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#creating-a%20server). I'm having a hard time understanding why errors thrown as a result of `hons_server.listen()` aren't caught by the try/catch. When I run my server twice I get the output:

```
$ coffee src/server.coffee
Listening to port 9090

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:632:11)
    at Array.0 (net.js:733:26)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

I'd like to know why the thrown error isn't caught, and how/where I can catch the EADDRINUSE error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Listen for the `error` event on the server isntance

```
hons_server.on 'error', (err) ->
    console.log 'there was an error:', err.message
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you know that? I know it wasn't in [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) and I can't find anything on which events the express server supports

Comment: Basically, the express server is the [http Server](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_server), which is an event emitter.

Comment: Does this still work in the newest version of Node? Please check out the answer below and update yours if needed.

Comment: It still works. from express 3.0.0 and onwards, the express object no longer inherits from `http.Server`, it's just a function that gets plugged into a server. The `error` event would have to be listened on from the server object, not the express function.

Comment: I expected the express `server.listen(function(err){...}` callback to support checking for errors, but this suggestion to listen for events like `server.on('error', function(err){...})` work very well

Comment: It works on vscode console, but in Windows cmd not, why is it?

Answer (score 28):

The accepted solution did not work for me on nodejs 0.8.22 and express 3.1.0.

This did the trick:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    if(err.errno === 'EADDRINUSE')
         console.log(...);
    else
         console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Also see [Node.js Express app handle startup errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322876/node-js-express-app-handle-startup-errors)

Comment: On express 4.17, I had to use `err.code` instead of `err.errno`. `errno` was `-98` and `err.code` was `EADDRINUSE`